# Is there any research on the effectiveness of learning verb tables?

Tags: reference-request, effectiveness, grammar, tables

I own books with verb tables for French, German and Spanish, i.e. for several languages with rather elaborate [verb conjugations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_conjugation). At school, I was made to learn such conjugations for French verbs and quizzed on them. For Dutch, Latin, English and German, we basically learnt the [principal parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_parts) and learnt to derive the rest from these.

However, are there any studies that show the effectiveness of learning verb conjugations *beyond the principal parts*? If yes, is this effectiveness only relevant to certain languages and not to others?

Comment: Related: http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/202/13

Answer (score 2):

There is some research on verb morphology, like [*Gor & Chernigovskaya (2004)*](http://genling.nw.ru/Staff/Chernigo/publicat/MoutonPap.pdf), which might be something useful to you.

Other than that, I can recommend that you have a quick Google Scholar search for something like "[verb conjugation SLA](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=verb+conjugation+SLA&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C13)", and so on.

If you are a student yourself, you might consider finding an advisor who'd support your own research project in order to find the answers yourself, if you can't find what you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks. I know how to do the research, but if I do it on my own, the site won't grow ;-)